# Is there a better way to parse this data file?

Tags: python, parsing, grammar

I have a text data file in [SPWLA](https://www.spwla.org/) format; I cannot find a specification for it. It contains physical measurements and/or rock descriptions from wellbore core samples. It's fairly gross. The example here is substantially simplified:

```
text = """\
30     1
     2001.10     0.00   2.11
40     1   2
     -1002.0000 34.5678
30     1
     2001.90     0.00   1
36     1    1
    Sst.Lt-gry. Pyr.
40     1   2
        18.72400    15.45700
30     1
     2002.90     0.00   2
36     1    1
    Sst.Lt-gry. W-cmt.
"""
```

This example contains data records for three depths in the wellbore:

- Record type 30 gives the depth of the following group of records.
- Record type 36, if present, contains a string in a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language).
- Record type 40, if present, contains the data whose fields are listed in another record type.
- I don't think there can be more than one '30' record for a given depth, and in my solution I assume there cannot.

There are several other record types, but I've left them out of this example.

I've written a parsing expression grammar (PEG), using Python [`parsimonious`](https://pypi.org/project/parsimonious/), to describe this format:

```
from parsimonious import Grammar

grammar = Grammar(
    r"""
    file          = data_blocks+

    data_blocks   = depth_block descr_block? data_block?

    depth_block   = "30" WS "1" WS depth WS NUMBER WS NUMBER WS
    descr_block   = "36" WS "1" WS "1" WS description WS
    data_block    = "40" WS "1" WS record_count WS DATA WS

    record_count  = NUMBER+
    depth         = NUMBER+
    description   = SENTENCE+
    field_name    = SENTENCE+

    WS            = ~r"\s*"
    NUMBER        = ~r"[-.0-9]+"
    DATA          = ~r"[- .0-9]+"
    COMPANY       = ~r"[-_A-Z]+"i
    SENTENCE      = ~r"[-., /ÅA-Z]"i
    """
)
```

And this parses successfully, producing an abstract syntax tree (AST):

```
ast = grammar.parse(text)
```

According to the docs, the usual approach now is to subclass the `NodeVisitor` class in `parsimonious` to crawl the AST, returning whatever you need from each node's special method (for example, the `visit_description()` method determines what gets returned from the `description` nodes). Here's my node crawler:

```
from parsimonious import NodeVisitor

class FileVisitor(NodeVisitor):
    
    def visit_file(self, node, visited_children):
        data = {}
        for record in visited_children:
            data.update(record)
        return data
        
    def visit_data_blocks(self, node, visited_children):
        depth, descr, data = visited_children
        descr = descr[0] if isinstance(descr, list) else ''
        data = data[0] if isinstance(data, list) else []
        return {depth: {'descr': descr, 'data': data}}
    
    def visit_depth_block(self, node, visited_children):
        _, _, _, _, depth, *_ = node.children
        return float(depth.text)

    def visit_descr_block(self, node, visited_children):
        *_, descr, _ = visited_children
        return descr

    def visit_description(self, node, visited_children):
        return node.text

    def visit_data_block(self, node, visited_children):
        *_, data, _ = visited_children
        return data
    
    def visit_DATA(self, node, visited_children):
        return [float(x) for x in node.text.split()]
        
    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return visited_children or node
```

I run it like so:

```
fv = FileVisitor()
fv.visit(ast)
```

The result is this dictionary:

```
{'data': {2001.1: {'descr': '', 'data': [-1002.0, 34.5678]},
  2001.9: {'descr': 'Sst.Lt-gry. Pyr.', 'data': [18.724, 15.457]},
  2002.9: {'descr': 'Sst.Lt-gry. W-cmt.', 'data': []}}}
```

Which is what I want, but my question is: is there a more efficient way to write this `NodeVisitor`? In particular:

- Can I avoid the `data = data[0] if isinstance(data, list) else []` business, which I seem to need to deal with the `data` (and `description`) node sometimes being empty?
- Writing things like `_, _, _, _, depth, *_ = node.children` feels a bit fragile and hard to maintain, which obviates solving the entire problem this way. Am I missing something?

I know I can do all this with string processing or regex, and I've done both. I'm interested in using a PEG-based method, because I'm drawn to the idea... but clearly I'm a little out of my depth! I guess I was hoping to be able to focus on maintaining the grammar, but writing that was relatively easy (assuming I've done it in a reasonable way!). The hard part was writing this tree crawler thing. So I'm wondering if I just swapped one kind of fragility (chained string methods or lengthy regexes) for another.

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch between the grammar and the visitor methods posted above. There are methods that don't correspond with a rule name.

Comment: In `data[0] if isinstance(data, list) else []`, what exactly is `data` if not a list? I.e. What exact case are you trying to guard against? Is it just `None`, or some parsed garbage?

Comment: @RootTwo Bah, you're right, good catch. I simplied everything (there are 3 other record types) and forgot to take those two methods out. Thanks!

Comment: @Graipher Thanks for reading... it's a `parsimonious.nodes.Node`, which has a very long repr containing essentially the entire data file's text (seems weird I know).

Comment: I'm surprised `descr_block` works, given that your sentences seem to contain spaces. Is it an ambiguous rule?  (Ending each line with EOL rather than WS would work to make it unambiguous, and then you could include WS in `description`)

Comment: @Pod Thank. I'm honestly not sure. I think I get away with it because the expressions are greedy. The thing is, if I start using EOL as a token, I need them all over the place.

Comment: @Pod The regex for `description` includes a space (but not '\t' or '\n').  Same for `DATA`.  So they will both end at a '\n'.

Comment: @kwinkunks Here is some VBA code to convert SPWLA files to excel spreadsheets. https://github.com/bolgebrygg/spwla.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get rid of the `isinstance(..., list)` checks by revising the grammar a bit.  I renamed `data_blocks` to `chunk` because I kept mixing it up with `data_block`.

A `chunk` is a `depth_block` followed by zero or more `other_blocks`.  The `visit_chunk` function then knows the first child is a `depth_block` and the second child is a possibly empty list of `other_blocks`. No need to check for missing blocks.

The `blocks` start with a regex that matches the numbers that start each block.  In the corresponding visitor methods, `visited_children` unpacking all start with one leading `_,` to match the regex.

I added whitespace (ws) to the end of each leaf-node in the grammer (number, description, the literals) to remove the WS clutter. The `nl` at the end of each block keeps the parser from extending a block to the next line.

```
from parsimonious import Grammar

grammar = Grammar(
    r"""
    file  = chunk+
    chunk = depth_block other_block*
    
    other_block = descr_block / data_block
    
    depth_block = ~"30\s+1\s+" depth number number nl
    descr_block = ~"36\s+1\s+1\s+" description+ nl
    data_block  = ~"40\s+1\s+" count nl number+ nl

    count = number
    depth = number

    ws          = ~r"[ \t]+"
    nl          = ~r"(\n\r?|\r\n?)" ws
    number      = ~r"-?[.0-9]+" ws
    description = ~r"\S+" ws
    """
)
```

Starting from the bottom, the `description` visitor strips whitespace from the matched text.  The `number` visitor strips surrounding whitespace and converts it to a float or int as appropriate.

For a node having a single child, `NodeVisitor.lift_child` return the value of the child as the value of the node. So `visit_count` simply returns the value of it's child `number` node.

The various `visit_*_block` methods use tuple unpacking to get the values of the important children nodes and returns an appropriate dict. `visit_chunk` assembles a dict from the component dicts returned from the `visit_*_block` methods. And `visit_file` returns a list of these chunk dicts.

.

```
class Visitor(NodeVisitor):

    def visit_file = NodeVisitor.lift_child
        
    def visit_chunk(self, node, visited_children):
        chunk, others = visited_children
        for block in others:
            chunk.update(block)
        return chunk
        
    def visit_depth_block(self, node, visited_children):
        _, depth, _, _, _ = visited_children
        return {'depth':depth}
        
    visit_other_block = NodeVisitor.lift_child
        
    def visit_descr_block(self, node, visited_children):
        _, descriptions, _ = visited_children
        return {'description':descriptions}
        
    def visit_data_block(self, node, visited_children):
        _, count, data_list, _ = visited_children
        return {'count':count, 'data':data_list}
        
    visit_count = NodeVisitor.lift_child
        
    visit_depth = NodeVisitor.lift_child
        
    def visit_number(self, node, visited_children):
        text = node.text.strip()
        return float(text) if '.' in text else int(text)
        
    def visit_description(self, node, visited_children):
        return node.text.strip()
```

I can't install parsimonious on this computer, so this isn't tested.

Looking at github, it doesn't look like parsimonious has been updated since 2018. I like using a PEG parser library called Tatsu.  One nice feature is the grammer lets you name parts of a rule and then refer to them by name in a visitor method.  For example, in the grammar, use:

```
data_block  = ?"40\s+1\s+" count:number data:number+ nl
```

then the corresponding visitor would look like:

```
def data_block(self, ast):
    return {'count':ast.count, 'data':ast.data}
```

without needing the unpacking statements.  I have a Tatsu-based solution if you would like me to post it.

Comment: Thank you for this contribution and the insight from your experience. I did wonder if Parsimonious had been abandoned, but it looked easier to wield than, say, `sly` or `pyparsing`. Anyway, I'm giving it a look now and I'll check out Tatsu as well.